# Apache Nutch REST API to retrieve data from server running Nutch?

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using the nutch REST API to run nutch searches on a seperate server. I would like to retrieve the crawled data back to my local machine. Is there a way I can use the nutch dump functionality to dump the data and retrieve it via the API, or am I better off indexing the data into Solr and retrieving it from Solr.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the REST API doesn't provide such functionality. The main purpose of the REST API is to configure and lunch your *crawl jobs*. At its core, it will allow you to set the configuration of a new crawl job and manage it (to some extent).

The transfer of the crawled data is up to you. That being said I do have a couple of recommendations:

- If you're sending the data into Solr/ES (or any other indexer) I would recommend getting the data directly from there. Both Solr&ES already provide a REST API, with the additional benefit that you might filter which data to "copy over".
- If you're running Nutch in a distributed mode (i.e in a Hadoop cluster) try to use the Hadoop libraries to copy the data to the destination.

If none of this applies then perhaps relying on something else like `rsync` or similar might be worth considering.